# Swap with setxkbmap pageUp and pageDown

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xkb

On Debian, I try to swap with setxkbmap pageDown with pageUp (and also Home and End), but I didn’t find options to do it in the `-option` option.

I try someting like `setxkbmap -layout fr -variant bepo -option caps:swapescape compose:menu terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp pgup:pgdn`, but `<key0>:<key1>` isn’t a syntax to swap keys.

So how to swap these keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, I found it. It is necessary to modify the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` file.

The relevant lines are the folowing ones:

```
…
    key <HOME> {    [  End          ]   };
    key <PGUP> {    [  Next     ]   };
…
    key  <END> {    [  Home         ]   };
    key <PGDN> {    [  Prior            ]   };
…
```

I just swap the definitions I found in HOME|END and PGDN|PGUP.